# Fixed issue of JQuery Form Validation Rule Check for ClassicEditor required

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

**First Add:**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="example-text-input" for="editor">Page Body</label>
     <textarea name="editor" id="editor"></textarea>
</div>
```

**Initialize CKEditor Object:**

```
var myEditor;
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .then( editor => {
            console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
            myEditor = editor;
            editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
                $("#pagesform").valid();
            });
        } )
        .catch( err => {
            console.error( err.stack );
        } );
```

**Create Custom Validation Method to Check Required for CKEditor:**

```
$ .validator.addMethod ("ck_editor", function () {
     var content_length = myEditor.getData().trim().length;
     return content_length> 0;
 }, "Please insert body content for the page.");
```

**Add Validation Rules (Mind to add `ignore: .cke_editable` in validate method):**

```
$("#formId").validate({
        ignore: ".cke_editable",
        rules: {
            title: {
                required: true
            },
            editor:{
                ck_editor: true
            },
        },
        messages: {
            canonical: {
                required: "Please choose a canonical"
            },
        },
        errorElement: "span",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.addClass("invalid-feedback");
            element.closest(".form-group").append(error);
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass("is-invalid");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).removeClass("is-invalid");
        }
    });
```

I found a solution for required `JQuery` Validation Rule.